# An object reference is required for the non-static field,method,or property 'tblSoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID'

Tags: c#

I am running into below error at line `tblSoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID = SoftwareImageTestPlanData.SoftwareImageTestPlanID`,how can I fix this error?

```
public List<SoftwareImageTestPlan>  AddSoftwareImageRecord(IEnumerable<SoftwareImageTestPlan> SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID)
{
    tblSoftwareImageTestPlan SoftwareImageTestPlan = new tblSoftwareImageTestPlan();

    foreach (var SoftwareImageTestPlanData in SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID)
    {
        tblSoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID = SoftwareImageTestPlanData.SoftwareImageTestPlanID;//error at line
    }

    return null;
}
```

Error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field,method,or property 'tblSoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID'

Comment: Rob - I looked at it,its not clear to me how to fix this error,can you provide guidance?

Comment: @Rob that is not the problem. The problem is that he is using the class instead of the instance in the for.

Comment: Please don't start local variables with a capital letter.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, just a silly error. Inside the for change   'tblSoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID = ...' to 'SoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID = ...'.

Comment: This code is confusing to look at because the naming conventions are exactly backwards: Class names should be title case, local variables should be camel case: e.g. `TblSoftwareImageTestPlan softwareImageTestPlan = new TblSoftwareImageTestPlan();`

Comment: It's also unclear why you're assigning to `tblSoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID` in a loop; it's only going to have the final value after the loop is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the class instead of the instance, change to as follows:

```
    tblSoftwareImageTestPlan SoftwareImageTestPlan = new tblSoftwareImageTestPlan();

    foreach (var SoftwareImageTestPlanData in SoftwareImageTestPlans_WithParticularSoftwareImageID)
    {
        SoftwareImageTestPlan.SoftwareImageTestPlanID = SoftwareImageTestPlanData.SoftwareImageTestPlanID;//error at line
    }
```

Also, your code is not following "conventional" C# coding convention. [See here for Microsoft guidelines on this,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) [and also here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)